# how to use hadoop map/reduce with nodejs server?

Tags: c++, node.js, hadoop, mapreduce

I've a web application with Nodejs server and HTML client.

I have server integrated with many c++ algorithms. To reduce server loading and for high performance, I wanna distribute my algorithms in parallel from server.

I'm a newbie to Hadoop and its Map/Reduce programming concept.

Question:

Shall I use clustering for this architecture?

Is this happens with map reducing?

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing up:

- Clustering, as in *data analysis* ("cluster analysis", but that is hard to pronounce)
- Clustering, as in load balancing (this would be easy to pronounce and precisey but not as cool as "clustering")

Make sure to distinguish these two.

Comment: Thank you. I'm sorry If I'm not clear to you. I did not get your context @Anony-Mousse. It would be thankful If I get answers for my questions. My main goal is Hadoop clustering with my server.

Comment: Your question cannot be answered. Your are confusing things. Your question is too broad, too.